# How to find the most important variable using CART?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, cart

Having sent ~100 job applications this year, I finally got a job. After all those months of searching, I was wondering which aspect most influenced my success (success = being invited to an interview or not). I created a dataset with independent variables (e.g. industry, language of application, version of CV). Then I did two things: I used rpart in R to create a simple decision tree and I looked at the variable importance feature from the randomForest package in R. My decision tree predicts that my CV mattered most (with the CV being the first split and thus the variable that most reduces Gini Impurity amongst all variables). My variable importance however tells me that it's the industry that matters and CV not at all.

Random Forest is a robust algorithm and certainly to be preferred over a simple decision tree. My question to you is if I should completely discard the results of decision tree or not. It's a greedy algorithm, so I don't care so much about the ranking of variables anyways. But I hesitate to discard the decision tree entirely because of the first split which is made on Gini impurity and should refer to the variable that best separates the predictor space among all variables.

I am happy for any comment or idea that can help me understand in how far a decision tree can help me solve my application puzzle. Thanks a lot!